# How to fetch multiple SM which were received after single CM request karate websocket

Tags: websocket, karate

- def socket = karate.webSocket(demoBaseUrlgame)

  - def body = {"_id":"p194","pid":1960939,"at":'#(gsauthtoken2)',"f1":'#(gametableid)',"f2":"023e86a7-d579-33a4-ac4f-9803beecaef1","f3":"webh5","f4":false,"f5":"","f6":"","f7":"","f8":"Windows","f9":"10","f10":"Chrome","f11":"96.0.4664.110","f12":false,"f13":"","f14":"","f15":false}
  - print "Body:", body
  - socket.send( '#(body)')
  - def loginuser2 = socket.listen(1000)
  - print loginuser2

In this one, i am sending one CM request but getting multiple SM, but only first one is getting fetched with or without the handler.
Is there a way where we can fetch multiple sm for one cm?

Comment: pass. I am unable to understand anything in this question. what is SM and CM !?

Comment: Cm means Client request and SM means server response (Websocket)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to "gather" multiple messages, you need to write a "handler" function with logic to "stop" when you have enough messages.

This is covered in the example, please read the docs: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate#websocket

I'm showing the line in the [example](https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/blob/v1.2.0.RC1/karate-demo/src/test/java/demo/websocket/websocket.feature) which you should study carefully below:

```
* def handler = function(msg){ return msg.startsWith('hello') }
```

So you can do anything, for example wait until some particular message, wait until some elapsed time, or wait until some count of messages. How you write that logic is up to you and your messages.